# Mutability confusion

Tags: java

My teacher showed us the following `class`:

```
public class Student{
   private int id;

   public Student(int ssn) {
     id = ssn;
   }

   public int getId() {
     return id;
   }
}
```

In the slides, my teacher said that this `class` was **mutable**.  I, however, cannot see why.

Could someone explain how this `class` is mutable? Or is my teacher wrong?

Comment: mutable?in the sense?

Comment: "Are *objects* of this class mutable or not..."

Comment: I've this code on the teacher slides and it says its mutable ... it doesn't make sense !

Comment: `id` isn't `final` - so it could be changed _inside `Student`_. From outside, short of reflection, it is immutable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most commonly used technique to make a class immutable, as stated in [Effective Java](http://goo.gl/3ZbpPr), requires that the class must:

1. **Not provide any methods that can change the method's state:** To avoid changing the state of an object after its instantiation.
2. **Ensure that the class cannot be extended:** If the class is extended by another class which is mutable in nature, classes that use the parent class (in your case, the Student class) in polymorphic contexts can't depend upon its being immutable.
3. **Make all the fields final:** To ensure that values assigned to fields cannot be changed, once they are initialized.
4. **Make all the fields private:** To prevent user classes from having direct access to the fields, and thereby prevent direct modification.
5. **Ensure exclusive access to any mutable components:** To ensure that clients of the class do not hold references to mutable objects that are referred to by the fields of the class.

Here, the class Student can be extended by other classes, and the field *id* is not final, as against points 2 and 3 stated above. Hence, the Student class is not immutable in true sense.